# Tab completion in mysql command line

Tags: mysql

I tried to test mysql's functions with select from command line but find that `tab completion` does not work

```
mysql> select Now() as current_moment;
+---------------------+
| current_moment      |
+---------------------+
| 2019-12-04 22:11:11 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select current_time;
+--------------+
| current_time |
+--------------+
| 22:11:27     |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If not reference to the manual, it seems very hard to play around with functions without the assistance of tab completion.

How could activate the tab completion.

Comment: Could you use your favourite text editor for this?

Comment: Are you using Windows command-line?

Comment: I am using Konsole in Kubuntu. @LajosArpad

Comment: Can you show us an example of something you typed which then failed to autocomplete? P.S. I assume you've read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-autocompletion.html?